# Find specific folders then search specific files inside them for a word

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to combine find and grep in a way to find folder names that start with k0 and search a specific file "test.log" for a word ERROR.

Something like:

```
find . -type d -name "k0*" -print | xargs grep ERROR test.log
```

unfortunately this command doesnt work as intended.

Comment: You mean "find . -type d -name 'k0*' -print" right?

Comment: You probably mean this instead: "find . -type d -name 'bin*' -print|xargs -n1 -I TEST grep ERROR TEST/test.log"

Comment: I fixed the -print typo. And no, I specifically want to grab these folders that start with k0 and search a specific file in all of them that is called test.log for the word ERROR.

Comment: Sorry about that. I meant "find . -type d -name 'k0*' -print|xargs -n1 -I TEST grep ERROR TEST/test.log" .. look at the -name and -path argument description in man find to find out what you need to write.

Comment: wojcii, yes, that did the trick. However, is it possible to view the name of the folder where the results are coming from? I see some random numbers at the beginning of each search result. Also, what does -l TEST do? are you aliasing the results and use them as a path name for the test.log file?

Comment: xargs replaces the label after -I with input. Look at the man page for xargs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, I am assuming you have multiple files named `test.log` in the folders whose names start with `k0` here:

```
for file in $(find ./k0* -name 'test.log'); do 
   grep -w 'ERROR' $file

done
```

You can make this into a one-liner command like this:

```
for file in $(find ./k0* -name 'test.log'); do grep -w 'ERROR' $file; done
```

It's executable on terminal if you just post it.

Comment: Thanks TonyGW, I am actually looking for a command line and not a shell script.

Comment: I get illegal variable name. Should I be a a specific shell?

Comment: what system are you using? try /bin/bash